# Event when moving itemstack to other inventory

Tags: bukkit, inventory

Every time a player issues a specific command, a virtual inventory is being generated from the contents of a MySQL table and then shown to the player. That's working fine.

Now, when the player is moving items from this virtual inventory to his own Inventory, it should check if the items are still in the database. If not, the event should be cancelled. And when the player moves items from his inventory to the virtual inventory, they should be added to the database table.

I have no problem with the MySQL queries, but I don't know which EventHandler I should use for the events (Player Inv -> Virtual Inv, Virtual Inv -> Player Inv).
[Bukkit Inventory Events](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/inventory/package-summary.html)

`InventoryMoveItemEvent` would be perfect, but it's only called when blocks (hoppers, dispensers, etc.) move items, not players.

`InventoryClickEvent` is no solution, because there are many different possibilities to move the items to another inventory:

- Shift-clicking would call the event only once
- Picking the item up and using the cursor for moving it to the other inventory would call the event twice.
- Picking up an itemstack and spreading its items across the other inventory would call `InventoryClickEvent` and `InventoryDragEvent`.
- and so on...

---

Anyone got an idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: I only have code for inventory creation (which is unnecessary here). As I don't know which event I should use, I don't have any code for the events yet.

Comment: Unfortunately, Bukkit's inventory events have many problems. You could use a repeating task instead, clearing the slot to simulate cancelling.

Comment: @FrancescoMenzani Aren't repeating tasks with MySQL queries causing server lag, especially when some players have their inventories open at the same time?

Comment: Right, you should use asynchronous threads for those tasks. You could use the Bukkit scheduler (recommended), or the Java built-in concurrency API, or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a simple solution to this, Use the `InventoryCloseEvent` and then check on close if the inventory contents are the same as what was in the database, if not then update the database with the new inventory and vice versa.

Comment: That _would_ work, I could lock the inventory to prevent modification from elsewhere while it's open and unlock it on close when the database is updated. But there's a way for players to cheat unlimited items: A player could take items out of the inventory and quit while it's still open, so no `InventoryCloseEvent` is called and the db is never updated. So the items are in the database **and** in the player's inventory. In addition to this, the player won't be able to access the inventory again, because it's still locked. I could unlock it on quit, but then players can cheat items.

Comment: You could handle the `PlayerQuitEvent` and then just do `player.closeInventory()` so it forces the InventoryCloseEvent on Quit